# Application Badge

Tags: iphone, xcode, badge

Hi guy it's possible put in the application Badge some letter?

Something like ON OFF?

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

Work but it's a number

in the Sadun's book (my last day bibble) i see

```
       [UIApplication sharedApplication] setapplicationBadge:@"ON";
```

But not work, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setApplicationBadge:` isn't in the [UIApplication API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html). My guess is that the method used to exist but was removed.

Comment: Or that it was/is private. She liberally used private APIs in the first edition, not sure about later editions.